# How long does it take for a flag to be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderators

Again, something which will be marked as a dupe sooner or later:

About how long does it take for a mod to review a flag? Because I raised a dupe flag and, after three days, I retracted it because I had received no response from it. Therefore, I ask: **How long does it take for a mod to review a flag (on average)?**

Comment: Dupe flags typically aren't handled by mods - they go to the review queue where they're reviewed by users with enough rep. Since a mod's vote is binding, they may not want to dupe hammer a question, especially if it's something they're not sure about. As for handling time - it depends. Mods have the average displayed in their mod dashboards, but, for SFF, I imagine it's ~4 hours (just guessing, though, based on the number of mods and their time zones).

Comment: Which question did you flag?

Comment: @Alex - The one asking whether citizens of the capitol could participate in the Hunger Games if they so choose.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Sorry, I meant people through the review queues, not mods.

Comment: @INTERESTING You can see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/148391) that it *was* handled. It hasn't been closed because only three people agreed with you that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Alex Right, but my flag wasn't handled. Also, look at the comment. _Eight_ people agree with me, they just probably can't vote to close it.

Comment: @INTERESTING That is how it was handled. It went to Review and users voted on whether it's a duplicate or not.

Comment: @Alex All it said was PENDING on my end.

Comment: @INTERESTING Try checking again. It should show "disputed".

Comment: @Alex - Nah, I already retracted it after three days of no response.

Comment: @INTERESTING What day did you flag it?

Comment: @Alex May 25th.

Comment: @INTERESTING Interesting. The review I linked above was actually *before* your flag. I wonder if perhaps your flag couldn't do anything because a question can't be sent back to the Review Queue until the existing close votes age away.

Comment: First, close falgs aren't handled by moderators. But more importantly, why on earth would you retract a flag just because it takes a lot of time to handle? That makes about zero sense.

Comment: @Gallifreyan The average shown on the mod dashboard is <2 hours, but I don't know whether that counts close flags or only flags that actually go to the mod queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For close flags, if nobody handles them in time, will be marked as aged away, as the [Meta SE FAQ says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/323179):

> [Close flags] follow the normal rules for close vote aging:
>
> - The oldest recommend closure flag, once per day, at the following times:
>
>   - 4 days after the last close vote if the question has 100+ views
>   - 14 days after the last close vote if the question has fewer than 100 views

Close flags send a question to the close votes review queue where it is almost always handled by regular users with 3k+ rep and not diamond moderators. You should be able to see if the review has been completed by going to the timeline URL (not linked anywhere) which looks something like this: `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/####/timeline`. For example, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/209620/timeline), you can see the reviews for the question you mentioned in the comments. Unfinished reviews are not shown in the timeline, and it's not easy to get a link to them unless you can access the close votes queue.

In practice, I only think I have ever had [aged-away flags on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321931/323179). (Close *votes* are another story.) As you can see [on the review page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review), the queues are always pretty empty. It's pretty [easy for close flags to be handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/323179): If one person votes to close, it's helpful. If three people vote "leave open" instead, it's declined.

My advice: don't babysit your flags ;)

Comment: Not almost always: **always**. Close flags don't even go to the moderator flag queue; they are *never* seen by moderators.

Comment: @Randal'Thor True but moderators can look at the queue and review from there.